Манифест не определяет активити Android
Язык проекта Java.
Подскажите почему у меня не получается декларировать активити в манифесте.
Я верстаю приложение для рисования. И мне нужно чтобы при нажатии кнопки в ToolBar открывалось активити с SeekBar для выбора толщины кисти, но не во весь экран,а в стиле диалогового окна. Для этого я привязал активити (activity_size) к классу SizeActivity.java — Класс той активности. и в манифесте объявил активити с названием SizeActivity, и темой ("HoloD" — Моя тема диалогового окна темы Holo.)
Но при нажатии через метод setContentView тема к активити не применялась, а через Intent приложуха вообще крашится.
Мой метод вызова активити:
Intent intent = new Intent(this,SizeActivity.class); startActivity(intent);

Что я делаю не так?
P.S если что в классе SizeActivity я уже указал:
setContentView(R.layout.activity_size);
Дополнительно:
Моё активити в манифесте:
<activity
android:name="SizeActivity"
android:theme="@style/Theme.HoloD" />


Если вам нужен диалог - его и используйте, зачем вам активити? setContentView() просто меняет разметку в текущей активити и всё. Чтобы реально запустить активность нужно использовать startActivity(). Почему у вас креш может рассказать только логкат, добавите лог ошибки в вопрос - расскажем в чём причина. Имейте в виду что каким бы то ни было образом обращаться к экземпляру одной активити из другой категорически нельзя, от этого только проблем поиметь можно.

попробуйте указать полное имя пакета активности в манифесте.

https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/components/dialogs

Скорее всего проблема связана с тем, что в манифесте не правильно указан путь до activity, нужно перед SizeActivity написать точку:
<activity
android:name=".SizeActivity"
android:theme="@style/Theme.HoloD" />

Так же проблема может быть из-за неправильно сконфигурированной темы, попробуйте удалить android:theme="@style/Theme.HoloD". Чтобы понять, почему тема не отображается, необходимо взглянуть на код вашей темы, иначе ответ дать трудно.
Чтобы более точно ответить на ваш вопрос, нужно больше данных, хотя бы логи креша
